# How can I determine the closest tag to a given commit using bitbucket rest API?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I want to get the list of commits since the last release, but since I have a lot of git repos to examine, I would like to do it via the bitbucket rest API instead of cloning each and every git repo I want to test.

If I do have a clone, my problem is simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

git tag | grep '<release-tag-regexp>' | sort <in-descending-order>' \
  | while read tag
    do
      tag_sha1="$(git rev-parse "$tag^{commit}")"
      ancestor="$(git merge-base HEAD $tag)"
      if [ $ancestor = $tag_sha1 ]
      then
        echo "Closest release tag is: $tag"
        exit 1
      fi
    done

 if [ $? -eq 0 ]
 then
   echo "No release tag found which is an ancestor of HEAD"
 fi
```

I wished bitbucket had a rest call for this query. As it looks, I seem to have no choice but to use the commit log and the tag list and construct a map myself.

Comment: Are you using bitbucket.org or Bitbucket Server?

Comment: on premise - so I guess it's bitbucket server

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to get the closest tag to a given commit via the REST API. However, if you already have the tags then you can get the list of commits between two tags by using the [commits REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.10.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45736094251408) and passing through the `since` and `until` query params.

Comment: I'll have to try if it does the right thing topologically, i.e. if it's the equivalent of `git log since..until` - but even if it does, it really doesn't help get me what I want: i.e. given any random branch, tell me what changed since the last release from that branch (or its parents)....